# What is the best way to write direcitves in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a custom directive using requireJS with AngularJS.

Here is below high level steps which I am following.

1. Configure requireJS.
2. define the imports using requireJS.
3. create a module.
4. with this module, create a directive.
5. In this directive, create controller, controllerAs and link options if necessary.
6. Use this module reference in other modules.

Here is snippet below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
define(["angular", "components/trade/trade_controller"], function (angular, TradeController) {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("csApp.trade.csTradeType", [""]);

needed for logging wrapped around it.
    app.directive("csTradeType", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "components/trade/_trade_type.html",
            controller: TradeController,
            controllerAs: "tradeController"
        };
    });
});
```

Guys can u please suggest me if this is proper way or guide me the better way.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason for down-voting??

Comment: Could you please put code part here? Always need some basic code snippets

Comment: @GulMdErshad: please find the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the proper way to create a directive. But, I will add below comments related to your question:

Each directive must be registered with a module. You call directive() on the
module passing in the canonical name of the directive and a factory function
that returns the directive definition.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
angular.module('app', []).directive('myDir', function() {
return myDirectiveDefinition;
});
```

The factory function can be injected with services to be used by the directive.

A directive definition is an object whose fields tell the compiler what the directive does. Some of the fields are declarative (for example, replace: true, which tells the compiler to replace the original element with what is in the template). Some fields are imperative (for example, link: function(…), which provides the linking function to the compiler.